# Is it possible to download an image from Google Document with original quality and high resolution?

Tags: image, resolution

Case: I have an image with original resolution 300 ppi. When I place this image to Google Document and try to download it -- the image has resolution 72 ppi.

Question: Does Google Document save an original image? Is it possible to download an image in high quality with resolution 300 ppi ?